# Any command to list the memory in MB rather than kB from /proc/meminfo?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

Cat, less , more , head tail etc. tried with all options that I am aware of. Can't find how to list the memory in Megabytes rather than kB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Can't find how to list the memory in Megabytes rather than kB.

> This will convert any `kB` lines to `MB`:
>
> ```
> awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024;$3="MB"} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
> ```
>
> This version converts to gigabytes:
>
> ```
> awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024**2;$3="GB";} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
> ```
>
> For completeness, this will convert to MB or GB as appropriate:
>
> ```
> awk '$3=="kB"{if ($2>1024**2){$2=$2/1024**2;$3="GB";} else if ($2>1024){$2=$2/1024;$3="MB";}} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t
> ```

Source [How to display /proc/meminfo into Megabytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29811379/3536342), answer by [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024)

Comment: Great,Not familiar with awk commands but  if I were to make a bash script out of it, do I need to change anything from it ? the else if part looks not bash type in the last one.

Comment: @j Sorry, no idea.

Comment: only total mem: awk '$3=="kB"{$2=$2/1024**2;$3="GB";} 1' /proc/meminfo | column -t |grep MemTotal

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, you may do it this way

```
#! /bin/bash
kb-to-mb()
{

        echo $1" "$(( $2 / 1024))" "MB

}

exec < /proc/meminfo

while read a b c
do
  if [ o$c = "okB" ]
    then
       kb-to-mb $a $b $c
    else
       echo  $a $b $c
       kb-to-mb $a $b $c
  fi
done | column -t
```

Comment: @Kamil sure enough. Updated the script to only convert lines ending in kB